# Is it feasible to select all the elements whose innerHTML are equal to a specified value with queryselectorall?

Tags: javascript, css, queryselector

I'm trying to select all the divs in the following example whose innerHTML are equal to "Practice".

```
<div data="t"><p>Practice</p></div>
<div><p>Practice</p></div>
<div data="t"><span>Practice</span></div>
```

I know xpath can do this job. I'd just like to know whether queryselectorall can also do this job?

Comment: As `querySelectorAll` takes a CSS selector, the answer is: no.

Comment: You should make another question asking "How can all elements with a certain text can be selected with Javascript?", I think that's what you want the answer for (that's what I would've responded if the question wasn't closed)